# org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: device.Dispositivo

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am developing an application that needs to collect data from database. I am using Hibernate. When I run the application, I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: device.Dispositivo
```

My hibernate mapping file is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="device.Dispositivo" table="dispositivos" abstract="true">
      <id column="iddispositivo" name="iIdBD" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
      <property column="nombre" generated="never" lazy="false" name="sNombreDispositivo" type="java.lang.String"/>
      <property column="descripcion" generated="never" lazy="false" name="sDescripcion" type="java.lang.String"/>
      <property column="descriptortipodispositivo" generated="never" lazy="false" name="sTipo" type="java.lang.String"/>
      <property column="codigo" generated="never" lazy="false" name="sID" type="java.lang.String"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The class 'Dispositivo' is an abstract class. I read Hibernate manual and it explains it is needed field "abstract" when the class is. How could I solve the problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The hibernate reference says :

> abstract (optional): is used to mark abstract superclasses in
>    hierarchies.

An entity may only be abstract if it's a superclass of other concrete entities. If it's a regular entity, mapped to a table, how would Hibernate instantiate your class if it's abstract? It won't magically implement the abstract methods of your class.